# Omnet++: Set total message length to be transferred from one node to another

Tags: omnet++

I have 2 nodes in my network and they have UDPBaiscApp for the communication between them. Node 1 sends message of length of 10kb periodically to node 2. Now I want to put a constraint of size of data Node 1 has. E.g., if Node 1 has 100kB data and it sends 10kB at once the the communication should end after sending message for 10 times. So how do I assign that maximum data that Node 1 can have?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in many ways, for example this way:

1) Add two variables in class `UDPBasicApp` definition:

```
long alreadySentBytes;
long limitBytes;
```

2) In `UDPBasicApp::initialise()` fill initial values:

```
alreadySentBytes = 0;
limitBytes = 100 * 1024; // 100KB
```

3) In `UDPBasicApp::sendPacket()` do the following modification:

```
void UDPBasicApp::sendPacket()
{
  if (alreadySentBytes < limitBytes) {
    std::ostringstream str;
    str << packetName << "-" << numSent;
    cPacket *payload = new cPacket(str.str().c_str());
    payload->setByteLength(par("messageLength").longValue());
    alreadySentBytes += par("messageLength").longValue();
    L3Address destAddr = chooseDestAddr();

    emit(sentPkSignal, payload);
    socket.sendTo(payload, destAddr, destPort);
    numSent++;
  }
}
```